# How can I make a ListView clickable? (NOT item clicks!)

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, android-holo-everywhere

I use an Adapter with a `ListView`...

I want to trigger the `ListView` click and disable item clicks (visually)

In my Adapter I do something like to disable visual click feedback:

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mParent).inflate(R.layout.row_set, null);

    convertView.setClickable(false);
    convertView.setFocusable(false);
    convertView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

    ...

    return convertView;
}
```

but that does not work either.

Setting an `OnClickListener` on a `ListView` isn't allowed as well, so I don't know how to trigger a click on the `ListView`

I would like to have unclickable items and a clickable listview...

Comment: set listener for convertView

Comment: what about this one convertview.setonclicklistener()?

Comment: The convertView is the ROW/ITEM! I want, that this is NOT clickable, but the ListView as a whole should have a click listener... I need something like a context menu for the listview, not for the items

Comment: use onTouch, when you touch, on action down, on action up, activate your method

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `ListView` in its own `ViewGroup` and making that clickable?

Comment: what do you mean? wrapping the `ListView` in a `LinearLayout` for example? I tried that, I even made my `ListView` not clickable and not focusable, but the View behind won't get the click delegated...

Comment: Yes, a `LinearLayout`, for example. Then make the rows not clickable and if you have `Button`s or any other `View`s that would be clickable by default then set their clickable property to false.

Comment: I tried making all items not clickable and/or the listview not clickable, but that did not work.. btw, my rows don't have clickable items, so this is no problem

Comment: I see you have a solution but just for clarity, I meant to make everything not clickable, except the `ListView` and make the parent `View`, such as a `LinearLayout`, clickable and set an `OnClickListener` to that parent `View`.

Comment: the parent view is clickable and has an click listener... with all items in my listview not clickable and my listview either clickable or not, the parent did not get the click... I tried that, but this way it did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your own touchListener,and to handle touch events

Comment: that works... although, it does not look good somehow... thanks though

Comment: No problem, if you will play a little you will get even a better response :)

Answer (score 0):

set     `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`
its row xml file and you can try for list view whatever best suit for you.check all op